# How do I configure magento to display prices including the TAX?

Tags: magento

I'm struggling to configure my Magento store to do the following with TAX.

I want to give a product a price which includes the tax amount specified i.e 20% so when I add it to the cart the TAX and grand total are displayed correctly.

For example:

My product has a price of £20. 20% TAX of £3.33 is built into the price. When this product is added to the cart I'd like the cart to display the TAX amount of £3.33 and the grand total of £20.

Right now all I can get is the grand total to add the TAX on top totalling £23.33. Also the display price is £23.33 not £20.

I'd love some help!

Answer (score 3):

Look under System/Configuration/Sales/Tax/Calculation

There are two important choices here

- Catalog prices include tax
- Shipping prices include tax

See [magento prices inclusive of tax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538770/magento-prices-inclusive-of-tax)

Answer (score 2):

Add this code in your phtml file where you getting the product price.

```
$_priceIncludingTax = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($_product, $_product->getFinalPrice());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display price on frontend with tax, go to:

- *System -> Configuration -> SALES -> Tax -> Price Display Settings -> Display Product Prices in Catalog*

You have three options there. To show product price:

- Excluding Tax
- Including Tax
- Including and Excluding Tax

Source: http://blog.chapagain.com.np/magento-display-product-price-including-tax/